# Catel PleaseWaitHelper doesn't work after update

Tags: c#, winforms, catel

I've updated the catel nuget package in my WinForms project and now the PleaseWaitHelper.Show() method returns a null reference exception. Hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on this?

Here is the code:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PleaseWaitHelper.Show("Logging in");
    ValidateAndLoginUser();
    PleaseWaitHelper.Hide();
}
```

The version I was using before was 3.6 and I've updated to 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

For apparent bugs, please create an issue at the issue tracker with a repro:

http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Then the team can look into this. It probably has to do with Application.Current.MainWindow being null, but I cannot be sure without a repro.